# How do I refight the boss from my first run?

Tags: splatoon-3, splatoon-3-side-order

My first time playing Splatoon 3 Side Order, I was able to fight

> Marina Agitando on floor 10F.

This boss has not shown up on any subsequent runs. Is there a way to refight the boss from my first run?

Comment: This is kinda spoiler-y...

Comment: @pinckerman Reworded to hide spoilers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by going left of the elevator before starting a run, you can interact with the headset in a cube which allows you to **relive memories**, including your first climb and the unique first boss fight.

https://imgur.com/a/OhfjRvp

https://www.reddit.com/r/splatoon/comments/1ayvzai/comment/kry15l7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button